# MySQL SELECT to display multiple values as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL “transform” query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140958/sql-transform-query)

I can't figure out how to compose a SQL statement to display the different values of a table as separate columns...here's an example:

```
Table A - Project
= = = = = = = = = = = = = =
ID | Project
= = = = = = = = = = = = = =
1  | Google

Table B - Tasks
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
ID  | Project ID    | Task_name | Date Complete
= = = = = = = = = =  = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
1   |  1            | Build     | 10/30/12
2   |  1            | Revise    | 11/15/12
3   |  1            | Launch    | 11/30/12
```

SQL outputs in the following format:

```
Website   | Build Date  | Revise Date   | Launch Date
= = = = = = = = = =  = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
Google    | 10/30/12    | 11/15/12      | 11/30/12
```

Comment: [Trying something](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) is a good start.

Comment: @Judy - not really a duplicate.  This is for MySQL, the other was for SQL server and the answer uses CTE's and ROW_NUMBER() / PARTITION BY, neither of which are available in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function but you can replicate it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select p.project as website,
  max(case when t.task_name = 'build' then date_format(`Date Complete`, '%m/%d/%y') end) BuildDate,
  max(case when t.task_name = 'Revise' then date_format(`Date Complete`, '%m/%d/%y') end) ReviseDate,
  max(case when t.task_name = 'Launch' then date_format(`Date Complete`, '%m/%d/%y') end) LaunchDate
from project p
inner join tasks t
  on p.id = t.`Project ID`
group by p.project
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c97e4/7)

Result:

```
| WEBSITE | BUILDDATE | REVISEDATE | LAUNCHDATE |
-------------------------------------------------
|  Google |  10/30/12 |   11/15/12 |   11/30/12 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily enough with self joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   p.project_id,
   p_build.date_complete As 'Build Date',
   p_revise.date_complete As 'Revise Date',
   p_launch.date_complete As 'Launch Date'
FROM Tasks p
LEFT JOIN Tasks p_revise ON p_revise.project_id = p.project_id 
  AND p_revise.task_name = 'Revise'
LEFT JOIN Tasks p_build ON p_build.project_id = p.project_id
  AND p_build.task_name = 'Build'
LEFT JOIN Tasks p_launch ON p_launch.product_id = p.project_id
  AND p_launch.task_name = 'Launch'
```